# Where did I go wrong with my implementation of finding a plane tangent to a surface?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, geometry, broken-code

I am working on finding the plane tangent to a paraboloid at a given point.

[image: author's solution:]

My code:

```
z[x_, y_] := 10 - x^2 - 2 y^2;
Subscript[z, x][x_, y_] := D[z, x];
Subscript[z, y][x_, y_] := D[z, y];
z[1, 2] + Subscript[z, x][1, 2] (x - 1) + 
Subscript[z, x][1, 2] (y - 2)(*The plane tangent equation*)
```

However, it doesn't work. My question is: where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's better to avoid subscripting in a problem such as this because subscripting just introduces unnecessary complications.

```
z[x_, y_] := 10 - x^2 - 2 y^2
zx[x_, y_] := Evaluate @ D[z[x, y], x]
zy[x_, y_] := Evaluate @ D[z[x, y], y]
```

`Evaluate` is needed because it is the result of the differentiation that should form the body of the functions `zx` and `zy`. Now the tangent plane can be written in accordance with the textbook formula.

```
tanPlane[x_, y_, x0_, y0_] :=
  Expand[z[x0, y0] + zx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + zy[x0, y0] (y - y0)]
```

`Expand` is applied just to make the result look nicer.

```
tanPlane[x, y, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> 19 - 2 x - 8 y
> ```

The plot may be made with

```
Plot3D[{z[x, y], tanPlane[x, y, 1, 2]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3},
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> None,
  ImageSize -> {200, 300}]
```

[image: tangent.png]

Comment: ,+1 Dear m_goldberg,Thanks for your perfect solution:)

Comment: `zx[x_,y_]:=Evaluate@D[...]` is the same as `zx[x_,y_]=D[...]`, but I think the later is more concise (if `x,y` are undefined).

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems and a style issue with the following line:

```
Subscript[z, x][x_, y_] := D[z, x];
```

1) You also have `x` appearing twice on the left hand side, once as a literal symbol `x` and once as a pattern `x_`. How is Mathematica supposed to know which value to place in the `x` on the right hand side?

```
Subscript[z,x][X_,Y_]:=...
```

2) In the command `D[z,x]`, you intended `z` to be a function, but it is just a symbol. The function rule is invoked only if you provide arguments.

```
Subscript[z,x][X_,Y_]:=D[z[x,y],x]
```

This is not enough, however, because your intent for the `X_,Y_` arguments is to evaluate the result with those values.

```
Subscript[z,x][X_,Y_]:=D[z[x,y],x]/.{x->X,y->Y}
```

3) Presumably you will never set `OwnValues` for `x`, `y`, or `z`  so this should be sufficient. I would still prefer to make the function argument a pattern and localize the dummy variables with `Module`.

```
Subscript[z_,x][X_,Y_]:=Module[{mX,mY},D[z[mX,mY],mX]/.{mX->X,mY->Y}]
```

Note that your definition may differ from what you thought it was if you set an `OwnValue` for `x` before the definition. Likewise, your definition will not be called if you set/change the `OwnValue` for `x`.

Comment: Also: setting `Subvalues` for `Substript`.. I suppose it sounds appropriate but really this doesn't make life easier :).

Comment: nice answer, but really my advice would be dont use Subscript at all, simple do `zx[x_,y_] :=`

Comment: I generally agree with not using display forms as function heads. Since the OP already has a working solution, I tried to focus on techniques that could be applied to other problems (localizing symbols and distinguishing between symbols, values, and patterns)

Comment: @Timothy Wofford,Dear Timothy Wofford,Thanks for your detailed solution sincerely.I will avoid using `Subscript`.

Answer (score 2):

The following tries to be as close to your code as possible

```
Clear[x, y, z]
z[x_, y_] := 10 - x^2 - 2 y^2
Subscript[z, x][x_, y_] = D[z[x, y], x];
Subscript[z, y][x_, y_] = D[z[x, y], y];
z[1, 2] + Subscript[z, x][1, 2] (x - 1) + Subscript[z, y][1, 2] (y - 2)
```

But I think it is a bad idea to use `Subscript` in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The principal question, which seems to be why the OP's code does not work, has been answered by Timothy Wofford, but I thought the following alternative to plotting the tangent plane might be appreciated, since it deals with the underlying problem in the question.

The equation of a tangent plane to $z = f(x,y)$,
$$z-f(a,b)=f_x(a,b)\;(x-a)+f_y(a,b)\;(y-b)\,,$$
has the same form as the differential $dz$,
$$dz = f_x(a,b)\;dx + f_y(a,b)\;dy\,,$$
with finite differences corresponding to the differentials.

This idea is easy to code in *Mathematica*.  The first form of the function `tp` below is for an equation.  Indeed it can even be an equation of the form $F(x,y,z)=0$.  It returns the equation of the tangent plane at `{a, b, c}`.  The second form is for a function $f(x,y)$.  It returns a linear expression in `x` and `y` that can be viewed as representing a function whose graph is the tangent plane.  The standard coordinates `x`, `y` and `z` are assumed.

```
tp[eqn_Equal, {a_, b_, c_}] :=
  Dt[eqn] /. {Dt[x] -> x - a, Dt[y] -> y - b, Dt[z] -> z - c, x -> a, y -> b, z -> c};
tp[expr_, {a_, b_}] :=
  expr + Dt[expr] /. {Dt[x] -> x - a, Dt[y] -> y - b, x -> a, y -> b}
```

The equation of the tangent plane:

```
With[{f = 10 - x^2 - 2 y^2, a = 1, b = 2},
 tp[z == f, {x, y, f} /. {x -> a, y -> b}]
 ]
(*  -1 + z == -2 (-1 + x) - 8 (-2 + y) *)
```

The function whose graph is the tangent plane to `f`:

```
With[{f = 10 - x^2 - 2 y^2, a = 1, b = 2},
 tp[f, {a, b}]]
(* 1 - 2 (-1 + x) - 8 (-2 + y) *)
```

A tangent plane to a surface defined by an equation:

```
surf = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 == 18 x y z;
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@{surf, tp[surf, {1, 1, 2}]},
 {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, {z, -2.5, 2.5},
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.8], LightBlue], Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

As a more general remark, in cases like the above the intention of the author is often to simply have a symbol available that is expressed by a subscripted expression. Mathematica has the `Notation` package with its function `Symbolize` available for this purpose, but the documentation of its use and purpose are not easy to find since there seems to be no link to the Tutorial page for the package (it can be found under "Notation, Symbolize, and InfixNotation").

Using `Symbolize`, rather than resorting to changing the OP's function names into slightly less intuitive forms using things like "zx" rather than `Subscript[z, x]`, the OP could use the subscripted variable names.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999 -- But your post is not really an answer to the question....

Comment: @Michael E2: Tried to clarify my answer to refer more clearly to the OP's question.

Comment: To me, it still sounds more like you're wanting to ask a question than explain what's wrong with the OP's approach.  I think it's a good question, but I can't predict how the community will receive it. Several times I would have liked to have such a Q&A to refer someone to.  The link I gave addresses only some issues.  I recall Jens (I think) defending a certain use-case, but I can never find it when I want to.  Consider asking a new question (and you can link to this Q&A and whatever else you think appropriate).

Comment: @Michael E2: I see what you are saying. I'm still fairly new to this forum, and I'm just starting to grasp its structure and philosophy. I was about to delete my question, but m_goldberg has already done that for me. I was also thinking about creating a post for the new question you were referring to, but I need to think about how to pose this first. I hope I'll be able to get back to this sometime soon, but things are pretty busy right now...